# How to prevent aweber to show login page without on click event

Tags: javascript, php, api, codeigniter, aweber

I am using codeignitor and doing aweber integration. All stuff working fine i dont want to see login page of aweber without clicking a button.

I downloaded from here https://github.com/aweber/AWeber-API-PHP-Library just change consumer key and consumersecret

```html
<a title="New account" href='<?php echo base_url ('/index.php/Welcome'); ?>' onclick>New account</a>


<?php
require_once('aweber_api/aweber_api.php');
// Replace with the keys of your application
// NEVER SHARE OR DISTRIBUTE YOUR APPLICATIONS'S KEYS!
$consumerKey    = "nnnnn";
$consumerSecret = "ddddddd";

$aweber = new AWeberAPI($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);

if (empty($_COOKIE['accessToken'])) 
{
    if (empty($_GET['oauth_token'])) {
        $callbackUrl = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        list($requestToken, $requestTokenSecret) = $aweber->getRequestToken($callbackUrl);
        setcookie('requestTokenSecret', $requestTokenSecret);
        setcookie('callbackUrl', $callbackUrl);
        header("Location: {$aweber->getAuthorizeUrl()}");
        exit();
    }

    $aweber->user->tokenSecret = $_COOKIE['requestTokenSecret'];
    $aweber->user->requestToken = $_GET['oauth_token'];
    $aweber->user->verifier = $_GET['oauth_verifier'];
    list($accessToken, $accessTokenSecret) = $aweber->getAccessToken();
    setcookie('accessToken', $accessToken);
    setcookie('accessTokenSecret', $accessTokenSecret);
    header('Location: '.$_COOKIE['callbackUrl']);
    exit();
}

# set this to true to view the actual api request and response
$aweber->adapter->debug = false;

$account = $aweber->getAccount($_COOKIE['accessToken'], $_COOKIE['accessTokenSecret']);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>AWeber Test Application</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
<body style="display: none;">
<?php
foreach($account->lists as $offset => $list) {
?>
<h1>List: <?php echo $list->name; ?></h1>
<h3><?php echo $list->id; ?></h3>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="stat">Subject</th>
    <th class="value">Sent</th>
    <th class="value">Stats</th>
  </tr>
<?php
foreach($list->campaigns as $campaign) {
    if ($campaign->type == 'broadcast_campaign') {
?>
    <tr>
        <td class="stat"><em><?php echo $campaign->subject; ?></em></td>
        <td class="value"><?php echo date('F j, Y h:iA', strtotime($campaign->sent_at)); ?></td>
        <td class="value"><ul>
              <li><b>Opened:</b>  <?php echo $campaign->total_opens; ?></li>
              <li><b>Sent:</b>  <?php echo $campaign->total_sent; ?></li>
              <li><b>Clicked:</b>  <?php echo $campaign->total_clicks; ?></li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    <?php
    }
} ?>
</table>
<?php }
?>
<body>
</html>
```

I want all data on the same page after clicking this button

```
<a title="New account" href='<?php echo base_url ('/index.php/Welcome'); ?>' onclick>New account</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you get your request token from AWeber you can have a button that goes to this URL:

```
https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={your_request_token}
```

That will open the AWeber login when your onClick runs. You can set the callback URL to be whatever you wish when you get the request token, so after the user logs in they'll be redirected to the next page and you can process the verifier token from our response. This is described here:

https://labs.aweber.com/docs/authentication

Comment: Hey @Kaitlyn can you please show me where to place this https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={your_request_token}  in button. thank you

Comment: You can just set that in your onclick. You can just do it in line like this:
`<button onclick="window.location='https://auth.aweber.com/1.0/oauth/authorize?oauth_token={your_request_token}';">Click here to authorize!</button>`